# c++ send recv on sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

I am writing a server client program that needs to communicate with each other. I have records stored in memory and I want to send all those records to the client. Right now I first send the number or records to the clients then I am trying to use a while loop to send each record but I am only receiving the first record on the client side. 
The client code is first:
    enter code here

```
      while(i < j){
      recv(sockfd,infobuf,BUFFERSIZE-1,0);//records from mem
      printf("\nrecords revieved %s",infobuf);
      memset(infobuf,'\0',BUFFERSIZE);
      i++;
      }
```

The server code is below:

```
     //send number of rec to client
     printf("count as j %s", recordList);
     send(reply_sock1_fd,recordList,strlen(recordList),0);
     memset(recordList,'\0',BUFFERSIZE);
     printf("\n count %d:", count);

     int i = 0;


     //look and send records to client
     while(i < count){
        printf("\ninside loopi (%d)", i);
        strcat(strcat(strcat(strcat(strcpy(recordList,bufRec[i].first), "          "),bufRec[i].last), " "),bufRec[i].userid);
        printf("recordlist %s", recordList);
        send(reply_sock1_fd,recordList,BUFFERSIZE,0);
        memset(recordList,'\0',BUFFERSIZE);
        i++;
        }
```

Comment: `strcat(strcat(strcat(strcat(strcpy(...` This is amazing!

Comment: @John you know, because sprintf() is unsafe ;)

Comment: @John Cool ... looks like lisp. :)

Comment: Is this a TCP or UDP socket?  Note that TCP doesn't preserve boundaries, one `recv` call can get data from multiple `send` calls, or vice versa.

Comment: It looks like same to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527927/c-socket-only-receives-first-send

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your problem is but you are not checking the return code from the `recv()` call. This should either be a positive number indicating the number of bytes actually received , a negative number indicating an error, or 0 indicating a dropped connection.

Note, it is quite common to get less data than you asked for have a look at the tutorial [here](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/sockets.html) for how to handle this situation.